# Is there a modern Obj-C short notation like @[array] or @{@"dict":dict} for CGPoint or NSPoint?

Tags: objective-c

This is great:

```
 NSArray *myArray = @[0, M_PI];
 NSDictionary *myDict = @{@"item":anItem, @"another":somethingElse};
 //etc.
```

But this is tedious:

```
[baseline moveToPoint:NSPointFromCGPoint(CGPointMake(0, baselinePosition))];
[baseline lineToPoint:NSPointFromCGPoint(CGPointMake(self.bounds.size.width, baselinePosition))];
```

Is there anything like `@(0, 0)` to simplify writing a point literal in code?

Comment: C99 compound literals to the rescue: `(CGPoint){ 0, 0 }`

Comment: @H2CO3 Whatever, posting that as an answer... I need to hit the rep cap...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

C99 compound literals to the rescue:

```
(CGPoint){ 0, 0 }
```

or

```
(NSPoint){ 0, 0 }
```

Comment: If you are assigning directly to a `CGPoint` or `NSPoint` variable, you can skip the cast and just use `CGPoint foo = { 0, 0 };`.  Also, if you actually want `0, 0` in particular, you can just use `CGPointZero`.

Comment: @Jim Except that it's not an assignment but an initialization, and as such, it has nothing to do with this question. This question addresses the issue of struct-valued **expressions,** and initialization is a statement, not an expression. (And honestly, did you think I don't know about that?)

Comment: @H2CO3, *"Nothing to do with this question"*? Seriously? The guy is looking for more concise ways to write code dealing with structs. He didn't restrict it to expressions only, that's just the example he happened to give.  It's entirely relevant to point out that there are times when you don't need to write the cast.  As for what you do and don't know, I don't know why you seem so offended, but please, leave the attitude at the door.  This is something a lot of people aren't familiar with.  It's not an insult to your intelligence to point out something you didn't mention that could be helpful.

Comment: Note: iOS does not support NSPoint.

Answer (score 1):

As H2CO3 points out, you can just cast a literal - this is plain old C, and `NSPoint`s and `CGPoint`s are just C structs. nothing fancy here.

As a consequence, there is no Objective-C shortcut, modern or otherwise, but there is an old macro which will save you a few keystrokes compared to the sequence you came up with:

```
NSMakePoint(self.bounds.size.width, baselinePosition)
```

You'll notice that the old macros and various constants used in the Cocoa API follow a natural English word order:

```
NSMakeRect(), NSMakeRange(), etc.
```

and for the options (e.g., in `NSString`)

```
NSAnchoredSearch, NSNumericSearch, NSCaseInsensitiveSearch, etc.
```

The concept that these options have in common ("search") is added to the end of the symbol name, as was the convention when the NSString class was designed.

The more modern APIs use a naming convention so names that belong to the same "group" begin with the same word(s). This makes it easier to alphabetize and greatly helps the autocomplete suggest the possible options for a parameter value. You can see this in NSOperation, for instance.